# Macaque V1 excitatory and inhibitory neuron tuning properties?

Tags: vision

I am looking for tuning properties of excitatory and inhibitory neurons in V1 of Macaque (like orientation and direction selectivity), similar to results reported by Niell and Stryker (2008). Most papers I found do not seem to classify these different cell populations in macaque. Any relevant papers you may know?

Thanks!

Niell, C. M., & Stryker, M. P. (2008). Highly selective receptive fields in mouse visual cortex. Journal of Neuroscience, 28(30), 7520-7536.